# Aggregate two broadband connection and output internet speed will be sum of both connection.

Tags: firewall

We are using 2 broadband connection and we want to combine internet speed of both connection into 1. suppose Broadband connection 1 provide 10Mbps and Broadband connection 2 provide 10Mbps now I want to combine both connections' speed into one. so, output speed with be 20Mbps.

Can you please tell us how to achieve this?
Does firewall provide such feature?
if you have any idea about any device please let me know.
thanks,

Comment: You would only be able to get 20 Mbps if you are using two sessions. For instance if you download 1 file, that would get 10 Mbps. Then if you start another download that would get an additional 10 Mbps. You would never be able to download 1 file using 20 Mbps.

Comment: @Crown Thank you! How is it possible? and if I do a speed test will it show 20Mbps?

Comment: @Crown, if there are multiple users then how it will work?

Comment: If you would do a speedtest it would only show 10 Mbps. There are many ways to do this (typically with a router), but we would need to know more about what type of network equipment you have and a network diagram or drawing to know more about how your network is designed.

Comment: @Cown we are using DSL and ADSL routers using wifi we are connecting all 18 laptops. we have 2 different ISP. there are 3 connections with one 1 ISP and 1 connection with another ISP. total we have 4 broadband connection each connection have a separate router. Now, I want to combine two or more connection and output speed will be the sum of connection and all the user will use from that output. it might be wifi or if need LAN cable then also not an issue.

Comment: What is the network topology and what are the router models?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: @RonMaupin No, yet not get any solutions. if you find anything or any other person find solutions please let us know here.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using 2 methods, either load-balancing and bonding.

Load-balancing splits traffic between 2 paths using some configured algorithms (round-robin, hash-based, ...). The maximum speed for a connection is drawn by the bandwidth of the interface is forwarded/routed through.

Bonding treats 2 path as an aggregate. If I remember well, the maximum bandwidth is equal to the sum of the interfaces's rate.
However, as far as I know, configuring bonding for links require that bonding is also configured at the other end of link. I don't think that you are able to bond link ISP links.
**EDIT** Thanks to Ron's comment, you can't bond multiple ISP links.

To achieve load-balancing, you can use software routers such as pfsense (or do it by yourself by configuring a linux server for example).

Comment: You cannot bond two connection to two different ISPs, and round-robin really doesn't work with two different public addresses from behind NAT. Really, only flow-based load balancing will work.

Comment: I appreciate the clarification on the inability to bond multiple ISP links.